# How to format a Scenario text

Tags: paragraphs

I writing currently on a paper and i have a short scenario, how my product can be used in the future. 
i saw that most people use italic font and indention to mark it as a story. Is it possible that there is allready a command for that or do i need to just format my paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are many possibilities. One basic approach would be to use, for example, the standard `quote` environment; this will give you some vertical spacing before and after and increased margins on both sides; another option would be to use this environment to define your own, adding the desired format changes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newenvironment{mysce}
  {\begin{quote}\itshape}
  {\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{mysce}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mysce}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For longer texts (or if indentation is required), instead of `quote`, you could use `quotation`.

Other (more sophisticated) approaches are of course also possible, but we would need a more detailed description of the desired layout.